# new boot issue for me ....but ... old boot question

Tags: boot, usb-drive, bootloader, usb-installation

1. I have put a fresh installment of Ubuntu 20.04 on an USB SSD.
2. I have unplugged it.
3. I have put a fresh installment of Windows 10 on motherboard SSD.
4. When I want to boot up with USB SSD, I need to use F12 and select the USB SSD to boot up Ubuntu 20.04.

Any way to just boot up, without to need to select the disk ? I have searched everywhere.

Comment: Select the boot device you want from your Bios.

Comment: Do you want the drive to be **portable** between computers, or are you happy to use it with only one computer?

Comment: Edit your BIOS settings: Change the priority of boot devices so the machine boots from USB first, and HDD later of USB is not available. Your BIOS is not part of Ubuntu, and varies from machine to machine, so we cannot provide more specific guidance.

Comment: ... portable usb sdd is what I want.

Comment: What alternatives are there to selecting the disk you want to boot up? If you always want to boot Ubuntu or always boot Windows you can set that disk as first hard drive in BIOS.If you want a choice between OS, then you need to select that disk yourself.

Comment: Maybe you have something that works already in the USB drive. Otherwise details in [this answer](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2447539&p=13974203#post13974203) should help you get you want in the USB drive. Many people would be happy to use F12 to select drive. But if you want to select via a [grub] menu, then you should install grub in the internal drive. If you have only Windows in the internal drive, I think it would be a bad solution, but if you have a dual boot situation with Linux (and Windows) in the internal drive, you will  get it automatically.

Comment: Yes. I am very happy with F12. No need for BIOS. Thank you.